# My donut object is purple

Tags: modeling

[image]

I already did UV editing then shading, donut was normal, like it should have been. But somehow changed to purple. I read that means something is not connected. In shading it is connected like it should be, only here in texture paint in left window you see there is donut texture selected but there is nothing below. Maybe there I acidentally pressed something.

Comment: The purple colour means that there is a missing texture. Check that all image texture nodes all have images selected and that you haven't deleted/moved any source files.